# What is wrong with my recursive filter function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

I have a react n-level app where the `delete` function is a recursive function utilizing `Array.prototype.filter()`. The data is an array of objects and in each object there can be an array that contains more data.

Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "hasParent": false,
        "hasChildren": true,
        "parentId": 0,
        "childrenIds": [
            3,
            5
        ],
        "text": "Opportunities don't happen, you create them.",
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "hasParent": true,
                "hasChildren": true,
                "parentId": 1,
                "childrenIds": [
                    4
                ],
                "text": "one",
                "childComments": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "hasParent": true,
                        "hasChildren": false,
                        "parentId": 3,
                        "childrenIds": [],
                        "text": "two",
                        "childComments": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "hasParent": true,
                "hasChildren": false,
                "parentId": 1,
                "childrenIds": [],
                "text": "one",
                "childComments": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "hasParent": false,
        "hasChildren": false,
        "parentId": 0,
        "childrenIds": [],
        "text": "Just one small positive thought in the morning can change your whole day.",
        "childComments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "hasParent": false,
        "hasChildren": false,
        "parentId": 0,
        "childrenIds": [],
        "text": "More data one",
        "childComments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "hasParent": false,
        "hasChildren": true,
        "parentId": 0,
        "childrenIds": [
            8
        ],
        "text": "More data two",
        "childComments": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "hasParent": true,
                "hasChildren": false,
                "parentId": 7,
                "childrenIds": [],
                "text": "More data two-two",
                "childComments": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `delete` function works for the top level of the data structure. For nested data, the `delete` function is not working. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the recursive delete function:

```
const HandleDelete = function(commentObj, objId) {
    const filteredObj = commentObj.filter((ele) =>{
            if (ele.childComments.length > 0 ) {
                HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId)
            }
            return ele.id !== objId;
    })
    return filteredObj;
}
```

Comment: You call the function but throw away the result.

Comment: @Pointy are you saying that I need to have a `return` in front of the line`HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId)`?

Comment: Well `HandleDelete()` returns a filtered list. When you call `HandleDelete()` inside the `.filter()`, you don't do anything with the return value. Probably the return value needs to be assigned to `ele.childComments`, or else there's no point to the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify an element inside the filter function, it can cause unexpected behavior and may produce incorrect results. This is because modifying an element can change the truthiness of the condition you are using to filter, which can lead to unexpected filtering results.

A better way might be this

```js
const HandleDelete = function (commentObj, objId) {
  // create an empty array to store filtered objects
  const filteredObj = []; 

  for (const ele of commentObj) {
    // if the object id matches the id to be deleted
    if (ele.id === objId) { 
      // if objId is unique, you can return here since you found the object to delete
      return;
    }
    // if the object doesn't match the id to be deleted,
    // check if it has child comments and recursively call the delete function
    // passing in the child comments as the new commentObj
    // otherwise, push the object into the filteredObj array
    filteredObj.push(ele.childComments ? HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId) : ele);
  }

  return filteredObj; // return the filtered array
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Pointy, you aren't doing anything with the result of the inner `HandleDelete`.

What I think you want is to map over the childComments first, then filter

```
const HandleDelete = function (commentArr, objId) {
  const filteredArr = commentArr.filter((ele) => ele.id !== objId);
  const filteredChildren = filteredArr.map((ele) => ({
      ...ele,
      childComments: HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId),
    }));
  return filteredChildren;
};
```

EDIT: changed order of map and filter, so it deletes top level items first, so it doesn't waste time recursing them only to throw away the result

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you aren't updating the `childComments` property of the parent object after removing the child comment. Try updating the `childComments` property on the parent comment by calling your `handleDelete` function recursively, and setting the result as the new `childComments` value:

```
const HandleDelete = function(commentObj, objId) {
    return commentObj.filter((ele) =>{
        if (ele.childComments.length > 0 ) {
            ele.childComments = HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId)
        }
        return ele.id !== objId;
    });
};
```

Comment: It's bad practice to mutate the values of the array inside a `filter`,  better to use `reduce` for mutations. Otherwise it would mutate the values of items in original array, but not delete the top level items matching the id leaving it in a weird half-state. Better to make this side-effect-free, and only modify items in the newly created array returned to the caller

Answer (score 0):

Just filter without recursion, and only then apply recursion to childComments, where present:

```
const HandleDelete = function(commentObj, objId) {
    const filteredObj = commentObj.filter((ele) =>{
            return ele.id !== objId;
    }).map((ele) =>{
            if (ele.childComments.length > 0 ) {
                return HandleDelete(ele.childComments, objId)
            }
    });
    return filteredObj;
}
```